# UIButton Touch Up Inside TouchesBegan

Tags: ios, xcode, uibutton

I create UIButton on my StoryBoard, and create Outlet for this UIbutton, then for Touch Up Inside I create some method. In standard button have method aka TouchesEnded

Maybe that is stupid questions, I new in Xcode but I ask
How I can switch on this button on TouchesBegan?

Thx

Comment: wt is ur problem ? and wt u want ??

Comment: the problem is that the event is processed after releasing the finger, but I need to once started touching

Answer (score 0):

create your `IBAction` for your `UIButton` and connect your button to `IBAction`. for when you tapped on button then your method is call.

Such like method,

```
-(IBAction)butttonTaped:(UIButton *) Sender
{
   // connect to your button
}
```

Comment: the problem is that the event is processed after releasing the finger, but I need to once started touching

Comment: @user2037857- then use UIControlEventTouchUpInside method of UIButton

Comment: I am use that, but event executes the method AFTER releasing finger, I need BEFORE when finger is begin touch button